# Typescript rxjs : is there any clean alternative to setimeout 0

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

Withing my angular app , I'm using this kind of treatment

```
myMethod(){
 ...
 setTimeout(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['mucomponent']);
 });
}
```

As I was told : `setTimeout` **without a delay** (0) seems to wait the next tick where all treatments are done to begin my treament. it's a planification for the near future.

Since I need this behaviour

Is there any clean aletrnative to do it the same with **typescript** or **rxjs** to do it better ?

Suggestions ?

Comment: Take a look to make it with decorators: https://netbasal.com/create-and-test-decorators-in-javascript-85e8d5cf879c. or use ChangeDetectorRef: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef if you need it

Comment: nitpicking on this : `with typescript ` -> it is already Typescript. You are using an existing function from the browser, it happens that calling a JS function in TypeScript and JavaScript is the same syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Interval or take in rxjs;

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { take} from 'rxjs/operators';

myMethod() {
  interval(0).pipe(take(1),
   ).subscribe(value =>
    this.router.navigate(['mucomponent']);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Even though the accepted answer might technically work, it is far from ideal. The RxJS team created the `asapScheduler` for exactly this use case.

```js
asapScheduler.schedule(() => this.router.navigate(['mucomponent']));
```

From the [RxJS docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/asapScheduler):

> asap scheduler will do its best to minimize time between end of currently executing code and start of scheduled task. This makes it best candidate for performing so called "deferring". Traditionally this was achieved by calling `setTimeout(deferredTask, 0)`, but that technique involves some (although minimal) unwanted delay.

Answer (score 10):

This should work, and is simpler than previous solutions:

```
timer(0).subscribe(time => this.router.navigate(['mucomponent']));
```

timer() takes 2 parameters, the second is optional. If 2 parameters are provided, the first parameter is the delay, and the second parameter is the period. If only one parameter is provided, it is the delay, and the timer will only emit 1 value (it won't repeat).

From the documentation for timer():

> If period is not specified (the second parameter), the output Observable emits only one
> value, 0.

reference:
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying some kind of scheduler here is timeout from RxJS

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timeout